How to simply reuse async user fetching logic in multiple Vue components?
I am fetching the OAuth User-Data and returning its corresponding DB-User-Value (from prisma) in my exported function getLoggedInAccount().
import axios from 'axios';
import { client } from './client/trpc.ts';

async function getUserObject() {
  const user = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/auth/guard', {
    withCredentials: true,
  });
  return user.data;
}

export async function getLoggedInAccount() {
  const userObject = await getUserObject();
  return client.auth.loggedInAccount.query({
    oAuthID: userObject.user.id,
  });
}

I want to use that User in the Frontend (Vue):
type Account = RouterOutput['auth']['loggedInAccount'];
let currentAccount = ref<Account>({} as Account);
async function fetchAccount() {
  try {
    currentAccount.value = await getLoggedInAccount();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to fetch:', error);
  }
}

This works perfectly fine, but I don't want to copy/paste that logic into every component. Due to it's asynchronous nature, I cant seem to find any simpler solution (e.g. just exporting a const)
Thanks, hope you can help :)

sounds like you want to use state management, like pinia or if you just need something simple, some simple state management with reactive API

You probably need the components to share common state, as suggested above, not just reuse logic. It's unlikely that the intention is to authenticate in each component again
